# Datatable not showing any data even I am returning the data successfully (I am using laravel in backedn)

Tags: jquery, database, laravel

I hope everyone is doing well, can anyone tell me why the data is not showing in the data table even there is any problem in returning the data from the backend and I am using an equal number of columns in my table with the number of columns returning, thanks in advance.

PHP (laravel code):

```php
public function getAllUsers() {
    $users = User::all();
    foreach ($users as $user) {
        $new = array( 
            'id' => $user->id,
            'fullname' => $user->fullname,
            'username' => $user->username,
            'user_type' => $user->user_type,
            "edit" => '<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>',
            "delete" => '<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>'
        );
    }
    // die(var_dump($users));

    return response() -> json([
        'data' => $new,
    ]);
}
```

HTML:

```html
<table class="table table-bordered" id="userTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FullName</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            {{-- <th>Phone Number</th> --}}
            <th>Edit</th> 
            <th>Delete</th> 
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>FullName</th>
            <th>Username</th>
            <th>Role</th>
            {{-- <th>Phone Number</th> --}}
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th> 
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Jquery Code:

```js
var dataTable = $('#userTable').DataTable({

    "processing": false,
    "serverSide": true,
    "bPaginate": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "ordering": true,
    // "order": [],
    'serverMethod': 'GET',
    "ajax": {
        url: "/getAllUsers",
        method: "GET",
        // data: { "fetchItems":"true" },
        dataSrc: ""
    },
    "success": function(data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    "error": function(e) {
        alert(e);
    },
    "columnDefs": {
        "target": [4,5],
        "orderable": false
    },
    "columns": [
        { 
          "data": "id" ,
          "render":function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return meta.row+1;
          }
        },
        { "data": "fullname" },
        { "data": "username" },
        { "data": "user_type" },
        { "data": "edit" },
        { "data": "delete" },
    ],

});
```

Result when i go to URL manually:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "id": 1,
    "fullname": "Jihad Abdulrazaq",
    "username": "jojo",
    "user_type": "admin",
    "edit": "<button type=\"button\" name=\"update\" id=\"1\" class=\"btn btn-warning btn-xs update\">Update<\/button>",
    "delete": "<button type=\"button\" name=\"delete\" id=\"1\" class=\"btn btn-danger btn-xs delete\">Delete<\/button>"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the getAllUsers to be like this :

```
public function getAllUsers()
{
    $users=User::all();
    $new= array();
    foreach ($users as $user){
      
      array_push($new,array( 
        'id' =>$user->id,
        'fullname'=>$user->fullname,
        'username' =>$user->username,
        'user_type'=>$user->user_type,
        "edit"=>'<button type="button" name="update" id="'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-warning btn-xs update">Update</button>',
        "delete"=>'<button type="button" name="delete" id="'.$user->id.'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs delete">Delete</button>'
      ));
    }
    // die(var_dump($users));

    return response()->json([
        'data' => $new,
    ]);
}
```

But it better to use [Eloquent resource](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources). When building an API, you may need a transformation layer that sits between your Eloquent models and the JSON responses that are actually returned to your application's users. For example, you may wish to display certain attributes for a subset of users and not others, or you may wish to always include certain relationships in the JSON representation of your models. Eloquent's resource classes allow you to expressively and easily transform your models and model collections into JSON.

Comment: Thank you Mehdi for the array_push correction, unfortunately I am using laravel 5.3 in which Eloquent resource doesn't exist, but for later laravel versions it will be my first option :) thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid using complex way ,this [DataTable](https://datatables.net/) is recommended

Comment: Great way to deal with datatable, thank you.